# How to delete a Date into a String Format?

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I would like to return an empty string from a date using the `replaceAll()` method. Turns out I have some problem with the regex so far :

Here is my sample code

```
private String delete(String str){
    String str = "2015-07-22";
    return str.replaceAll("-2[0-9]{7}","");
}
```

I am not sure this `"-2[0-9]{7}"` is the right regex in my opinion.
Why doesn't this code return `""` ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to achieve? "return an empty string" ?

Comment: Delete? Wouldn't it be "return a date"?

Comment: If you want to return an empty string, why not just write `return "";` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` will match the desired pattern:

```
"2015-07-22".replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", "") // ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about `"-"` sign.

If you whant to do it like this (it wont work for different date patterns nor date < 2000 year) do either:

`str.replaceAll("2[0-9\\-]{9}","")`

or

`str.replaceAll("2[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}","")`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match cause of -.

Here is a better regex :

```
^[0-9]{4,}(-([0-9]{2})){2}$
```

If you have any question about it, you can find the documentation here : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

You can also test your regex with this web site : 
http://myregexp.com/